# how to read a file in java from path my path is like: "path": "C:\\somefolder\\otherfoldet\\abc.war\\acm.jar\\a.properties"

Tags: java, json

How to read a file from the specified path in java

Code

```
public void readPropertyFile(String path)throws IOException {

File fp = new File(path);
        FileReader  reader = new FileReader(fp);//        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\json\trm\trm.jar\quartz.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(reader)
}

Exption:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\json\trm\trm.jar\quartz.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading from the inside of a WAR (acm.war) or JAR (acm.jar) you need [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) or [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html).

```
String entryName = "a.properties";
Path path = Paths.get("C:", "somefolder", "abc.war");

try (ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
  ZipEntry entry;
  while ((entry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (entry.getName().equals(entryName) {
      // read zipIn content here to get the entry
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please give me more details about the code how i write?

Comment: I want to read a "load.properties" and path is like as follows            
 String path = "C:/folder/folder/Spring.war/my.jar/load.properties";